# Importing JPEGs into Acrobat ruins edges

Tags: pdf, printing, images, adobe-acrobat, jpeg

I'm working with a PDF in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, and trying to import a relatively high quality JPEG. Despite disabling any compression-related options that I can see, the edges of the imported image are always low quality.

### Background

The PDF was created from a webpage by selecting <kbd>File</kbd>, <kbd>Print</kbd> in Firefox, then selecting the *Adobe PDF* driver in the dialogue:

[image]

I then opened the `Properties` dialogue and set the following settings:

[image]

I also modified the *High Quality Print* preset to turn both `Compression` and `Downsampling` off for images.

### The Problem

Despite all of the above setup to ensure imported images don't have their quality reduced, the edges of the imported images are badly artifacted, and this is amplified when the image is reduced to a smaller size.

The JPEG in question is a 500KB 450x165 logo that was originally an Illustrator EPS vector file, which I opened in Photoshop to resize and save to a raster JPEG.

This is the original image as previewed by Windows Photo Viewer:

[image]

This is the image immediately after being imported into the PDF with Acrobat (notice especially the bottom edges):

[image]

This is the image when resized to the size I need it to be in the PDF:

[image]

**How can I import the image into the PDF without introducing any artifacts?**

The nature of this document requires that it both render and print as professionally as possible, so this is not an ideal situation at all, and I would really appreciate some help with getting it to look good. Thank you.

Comment: I mentioned this in my question. There's no way to import an EPS directly into Acrobat, and I don't have access to the new version of Illustrator that the EPS file was created with, so I had to use Photoshop to open it (double-clicking the canvas and browsing to it), then using `Image Size` to resize it and saved it as a JPEG. I then used Acrobat's `Add Image` to import the JPEG into my PDF file.

Comment: Image quality could be better if in Photoshop you convert the logo to advanced object before resizing it and if you save it as [TIFF instead of JPEG](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/02/how_to_importpl_1/)

Comment: @spike_66 Do you mean convert it to smart object? If so, how that would be done? I can't find any information on it.

Comment: In Photoshop right click on the layer. In the menu click Convert to Smart Object.